# If two DateTime stamps are the same in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have created a simple appointment system, and I now need to display something inside a loop if there's two or more appointments with the same date and time. The appointments are displayed in order of time, so they're just appearing one after the other.

***Controller***

```
def index
  @todays_apps = current_user.appointments.order(time ASC)
end
```

***View***

```
<% @todays_apps.each do |app| %>
  <%= app.business_name %>
  <%= app.business_address %>
  <%= app.time %>
<% end %>
```

I'm looking to display a message or icon the appointment shares a date and time with another appointment. Tried a collection of things with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can group your collection by time and modify your iteration accordingly. You can group it like

```
@todays_apps.group_by(&:time)
```

The outcome will be something like

```
=> { timestamp1 => [app1,app2], timestamp2 => [app3], timestamp3 => [app4]}
```

---

Or you can try a quick hacky way like:

```
  <% previous_time = nil %>
  <% @todays_apps.each do |app| %>
    <%= app.business_name %>
    <%= app.business_address %>
    <%= 'Your message or class or anything' if previous_time == app.time %>
    <%= previous_time = app.time %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this:

**controller:**

```
def index
  @appointments = current_user.appointments.order("time ASC")
  @todays_apps = @appointments.group_by(&:time)
end
```

**View:**

```
<% @todays_apps.each do |time, appointments| %>
  <%= time %>
  <% appointments.each do |appointment| %>
    <%= appointment.business_name %>
    <%= appointment.business_address %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It will list all the appointments for particular time.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer @rails-guy but this is not quite what I'm looking for. Please see this quick image: http://cl.ly/image/2O3y1V2N3w3c - I just need a way to signal the user that two appointments are taking place at the same time, as this is not always a bad thing.